Replacing words in get-aduser data output
There is a script that displays active domain users in datagridview. Is it possible to replace "true" and "false" on "active" and "disabled"?

#...
$Users = Get-ADuser -filter * -Properties Name, UserPrincipalName, Enabled
samaccountname).samaccountname
Foreach ($User in $Users)
{
    $DataGridView1.Rows.Add($User.Name, $User.UserPrincipalName, $User.Enabled)
    
}
#...


You can simply use the ternary syntax.
$Status = If ($User.Enabled) { "active" } Else { "disabled" }
$DataGridView1.Rows.Add($User.Name, $User.UserPrincipalName,  $Status)

In Powershell 7, You can do:
$Status = $User.Enabled ? "active" : "disabled"
$DataGridView1.Rows.Add($User.Name, $User.UserPrincipalName,  $Status)

